# how to mount emmc partition using adb

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, partitions

Yesterday, I tried to root my Micromax Unite 2 smartphone. I followed [this](http://www.androidrootguide.com/2015/04/how-to-flash-stock-rom-firmware-on-micromax-unite-2-a106.html) tutorial. Before flashing the zip files I had the latest Android Lollipop installed.

I flashed all the zip using the sp flash tool. After completion, I got OK message. Then according to procedure I needed to wipe data factory, so I started my phone in recovery mode and tried to wipe content but I got error **Unable to mount internal storage**.

I have no idea about how should I mount. I tried to mount through recovery but failed to mount.

Does anybody having any idea how could I mount internal SD card back. Currently it is showing internal storage 0 MB.

I newbie in adb usage I tried to mount using adb but I didn't got any useful information.

Comment: Kindly post comment for down voting.

Answer (score 0):

to mount all the partitions as R/W from adb execute this commands

```
adb kill-server
adb root
adb remount
```

if there is any error message let me know so I can update the answer

Comment: @lord-rafl-adolf I did as you said I got `remount failed: Success`, does it happen correctly or not. The message itself is in confused way.

Comment: yes the error is confusing ... it's a a fail not a success ,is the internal storage a physical partition or an emulated one (on new phones internal storage is under data/media and mounted to /emulated/0) ,and what recovery are you using ?

Comment: it is a physical partition and I am trying to mount it. When I try to mount or wipe user data it shows me error `can't mount emmc@cache`  and other can't mount error. I am unable flash anything on it. Is there any way to mount file system again as the phone is not able to mount any folders and partitions too.